# How can I write reverse by foldr efficiently in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Note that the trivial solution

```
reverse a = foldr (\b c -> c ++ [b] ) [] a
```

is not very efficient, because of the quadratic growth in complexity. If have tried to use the usual foldl to foldr conversion (blindly), but my attempt

```
foldr (\b g x -> g ((\x old -> x:old) x b)) id list []
```

did not work as I expected.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
reverse bs = foldr (\b g x -> g (b : x)) id bs []
```

Though it's usually really better to write it using [foldl'](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-):

```
reverse = foldl' (flip (:)) []
```

Comment: Chris: Let's just say: The accumulator has type [a] -> [a].  It's basically building up a lot of encapsulated lambdas, that add the list's elements to the front of what's passed - [].

Comment: @Chris I personally prefer it in point-free notation, it is more readable (to me) that way: `reverse xs = foldr f id xs [] where f x r = r . (x:)`. So when the result of `foldr f id xs` is finally applied on `[]`, the `f x1 r1` is called, which produces `r1 . (x1:) $ []` at which point `r1` is forced. In the end the whole chain `id.(xn:). ... .(x2:).(x1:)` is applied to `[]`. This uses the standard Haskell way of encoding the open-ended (aka *"difference-"*) lists as chains of list-producing functions, `:: [a] -> [a]`. Same is used in `Data.Sequence` I believe.

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where `foldl'` is *not* better. The action of blindly applying a lazy constructor is never delayed because there is never any benefit to doing so. In the event that the code produced is actually different, it can only be worse.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following:

```
foldr (<>) seed [x1, x2, ... xn] == x1 <> (x2 <> (... <> (xn <> seed)))
```

Let's just "cut" it into pieces:

```
(x1 <>) (x2 <>) ... (xn <>)  seed
```

Now we have this bunch of functions, let's compose them:

```
(x1 <>).(x2 <>). ... .(xn <>).id $ seed
```

`((.), id)` it's `Endo` monoid, so

```
foldr (<>) seed xs == (appEndo . foldr (mappend.Endo.(<>)) mempty $ xs) seed
```

For left fold we need just `Dual` monoid.

```
leftFold (<>) seed xs = (appEndo . getDual . foldr (mappend . Dual . Endo . (<>)) mempty $ xs) seed
```

`(<>) = (:)` and `seed = []`

```
reverse' xs = (appEndo . getDual . foldr (mappend . Dual . Endo . (:)) mempty $ xs) []
```

Or simple:

```
reverse' xs = (appEndo . foldr (flip mappend . Endo . (:)) mempty $ xs) []
reverse' xs = (foldr (flip (.) . (:)) id $ xs) []
reverse' = flip (foldr (flip (.) . (:)) id) []
```

Comment: As a beginner, I downvoted this answer because while teaching how to implement reverse (clearly the OP is also a freshman), the answer couldn't help but throw in category theory jargon just for kicks.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to transform 1:2:3:[] into (3:).(2:).(1:) and apply it to []. Thus:

```
reverse' xs = foldr (\x g -> g.(x:)) id xs []
```

The meaning of the accumulated g here is that it acts on its argument by appending the reversed partial tail of xs to it.

For the 1:2:3:[] example, in the last step x will be 3 and g will be (2:).(1:).

Answer (score 0):

```
foldl (\acc x -> x:acc) [] [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Wrong place for answer, but just what I was looking for.

Comment: I want to say that I realized that my answer was not correct very long time ago, but to my amazement many people have already voted it up (in total I got 5 votes up and 5 votes down). I think sometime people land to this page when looking for exactly this answer, thus I decided to keep it here because in the end it is all about helping others to find answers they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

old question, I know, but is there anything non-optimal about this approach, it seems like foldr would be faster due to lazy evaluation and the code is fairly concise:

```
 reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
 reverse' = foldr (\x acc -> acc ++ [x]) []
```

is (++) significantly slower than (:), which requires a few logical twists as shown in FUZxxl's answer

Comment: This implementation is O(n^2) on the length of the list.  At every step the current `acc` becomes garbage and a new list is created with `x` as the last element.  Lazy evaluation only changes _when_ this happens.  In a strict language it would happen prior to `reverse'` returning.  In Haskell it will occur when  you force the result list.

Comment: ah, that makes perfect sense. Did not think about the fact that it would create a new list at each iteration. Thanks!

Comment: Some statically-available `++` applications can come out in the wash, but here they'll all actually happen and you will pay dearly for them.

Answer (score 0):

`reverse = foldl(\ a b -> b :a) []`