# Haskell reverse function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Very new to Haskell, and trying to create my own reverse function. Wrote this here, but it always returns an empty list [] :

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' xs = [xs !! k | k <- [((length xs) - 1)..0]]
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: does `[length xs - 1, length xs - 2..0]` work?

Comment: If you're not comfortable with recursion yet, before looking at other implementations try defining `reverse` another way by filling in the following: `reverse [] = ... ; reverse (x:xs) = ...` and think of it as "the reverse of the empty list is ... and the reverse of `x` consed with the list `xs` is ..."

Comment: Note that it's generally questionable to access lists by index. They are specifically designed so you can easily deconstruct them _recursively_, from the head element by element, but perform very badly when you request an element at arbitrary position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034787/groovy) mentioned, Haskell ranges are mostly incremental - that is, it has no idea how to construct a decreasing list unless you give it some hint. Have a look at a ghci session below:

```
Prelude> [5..0]
[]
Prelude> [5,4..0]
[5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

So, you can construct something like this:

```
foo xs = [(length xs-1), (length xs -2)..0]
rev xs = [xs !! k| k <- foo xs]
```

which checks out in ghci like this:

```
Prelude> rev [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Have a look at [Unexpected result while reversing a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117057/haskell-reverse-a-list) and [How can I write reverse by foldr efficiently in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862881/how-can-i-write-reverse-by-foldr-efficiently-in-haskell/7862945#7862945) for other ideas on reversing a list.

Comment: But don't forget to check with empty list and singleton list

Comment: You could use a `where` binding in `foo` to avoid computing the length of `xs` twice.

Answer (score 5):

oftentimes it helps to invent some invariant and write down some laws of preservation for it. Here notice that

```
reverse xs     = reverse xs ++ []
reverse (x:xs) = (reverse xs ++ [x]) ++ []
               = reverse xs ++ ([x] ++ [])
               = reverse xs ++ (x:[])
reverse (x:(y:xs)) =
               = reverse (y:xs) ++ (x:[])
               = reverse xs ++ (y:x:[])
......
reverse (x:(y:...:(z:[])...)) =
               = reverse [] ++ (z:...:y:x:[])
```

so if we define

```
reverse xs = rev xs []  where
  rev (x:xs) acc = rev xs (x:acc)
  rev []     acc = acc
```

we're set. :) I.e., for a call `rev a b`, the concatenation of reversed `a` and `b` is preserved under a transformation of taking a head element from `a` and prepending it to `b`, *until* `a` is empty and then it's just `b`. This can even be expressed with the use of [higher-order function `until`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3auntil) following the English description, as

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
reverse = snd . until (null.fst) (\(a,b)-> (tail a,head a:b)) . (, [])
```

We can also define now e.g. an `revappend` function, using exactly the same internal function with a little tweak to how we call it:

```
revappend xs ys = rev xs ys  where
  rev (x:xs) acc = rev xs (x:acc)
  rev []     acc = acc
```

Answer (score 0):

That is my form to create my own reverse function with recursion. this function is very util for not define auxiliar functions.

`list = []
reverse [x] = list ++ [x]
reverse = list ++ [last l] ++ reverse (init l)`